# Can't find dropdown list in RowDataBound event

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm following this example http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/Editable_GridView.aspx to build an editable GridView control.
I have this code in my GridView:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Negócio">
<ItemTemplate> 
    <asp:Label ID="lblNegocio" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Negocio") %>'></asp:Label> 
</ItemTemplate> 
<EditItemTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNegocio" runat="server" /> 
</EditItemTemplate> 
<FooterTemplate> 
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNewNegocio" runat="server" />
</FooterTemplate>
```

Now, I'm trying to fill the dropdown in the EditItemTemplate with some dynamic values just as the example says, in the RowDataBound Event of the grid. But when I do this, the FindControl method always returns Nothing:

```
Protected Sub gdvRegraRotationDefault_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gdvRegraRotationDefault.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
    Dim ddlNegocio As DropDownList = e.Row.FindControl("ddlNegocio")
End If
```

End Sub

If I can't find the Dropdown I can't load the values in it and when I'm going to edit de entry it will be empty.

Can someone help me?

Thank you (:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the RowEditing-Event, as your DropDownList should only be shown when clicking Edit.
But first, you have to bind the GridView newly as the GridView now needs to render different controls for the edit row:

```
protected void gdvRegraRotationDefault_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    gdvRegraRotationDefault.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    gdvRegraRotationDefault.DataBind();

    GridViewRow row = gdvRegraRotationDefault.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];
    DropDownList ddl = row.FindControl("ddlNegocio") as DropDownList;

    //now do databinding for DropDownList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The FindControl always return null because when your in the RowDataBound event you can get the label only.

If you want to fill the DropDownList when you click the edit button on the grid, then you have to use the GridViewRowEditing event.

Comment: Right, but in this event I can't use the FindControl method because the class GridViewEditEventArgs has no access to the Row property. How should I do it?

Comment: You have tow choices, either parse the sender to a GridViewRow or use the e.NewEditIndex which is the index of the Row being edited, then you find the control in that row.

Comment: Dim row As GridViewRow = gdvRegraRotationDefault.Rows(e.NewEditIndex) Dim ddlNegocio As DropDownList = row.FindControl("ddlNegocio") //Still returns Nothing ):

Comment: As Jan-Frederik Carl said, you have to do a GridView.DataBind(), after that you can access your control.

Answer (score 0):

In the RowDataBound event, simply add the following conditional:

```
if (myGridView.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
{
     //do work
}
```

Comment: Hmmm I think you didn't understand my problem man, that won't help me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yes, but Jan-Frederik Carl and yahya kh already helped me solve my problem. Thank you.